# What is a `TimeEvent` object in Javascript? What methods and properties does it have?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm using react-timeseries charts. In it, the `ScatterChart` component has a prop called `radius` which can accept a function.

The function takes two parameters. `Event` of type `TimeEvent` and `column` of type  `String`.

While `column` is easy enough to understand, I have no idea what `TimeEvent` is made of. What are its methods? What properties does it have? How can I use it to set the radius and styles of the `ScatterChart`?

The documentation is also really poor and I can't find any info about `TimeEvent` object in the `pondjs` library it is using.

As a front end developer, how do I go about figuring out different objects used by different libraries when documentation is not available? Right now, I'm using Chrome's dev tools, in which I see this

[image]

I have no idea what I can make of this image. What else can I do to get more info?

Answer (score 2):

The browser's `TimeEvent` which is inspectable in Chrome's dev tools is the class of events fired by SVG animations on `begin`, `repeat` and `end`. Let's take the MDN SVG animation example and add some event listeners.

```js
let svg = document.querySelector('animate');

svg.addEventListener('begin' , ev => console.log('begin animation: class' , ev.constructor.name));
svg.addEventListener('repeat', ev => console.log('repeat animation: class', ev.constructor.name));
svg.addEventListener('end'   , ev => console.log('end animation: class'   , ev.constructor.name));
```

```html
<!-- Learn about this code on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_animation_with_SMIL -->

<svg width="300" height="100">
    <title>Attribute Animation with SMIL</title>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="300" height="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
    <circle cx="0" cy="50" r="15" fill="blue" stroke="black" stroke-width="1">
      <animate
        attributeName="cx" from="0" to="100"
        dur="5s" repeatCount="3" />
    </circle>
  </svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

`TimeEvent` is a data structure provided by the `pond.js` library you are using: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pondjs#what-does-it-do

You can find its source code [here](https://github.com/esnet/pond/blob/master/packages/pond/src/event.ts#L706-L722).